# PHP change xml output value of SoapClient

Tags: php, xml, if-statement, soap, soap-client

I have the following php code for a Soap XML

```
<?php
$time = time();
$authcode = "code";
$client = new SoapClient('link',array("trace" => 1,"exceptions" => 0,'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
$result=$client->GetCikkekAuth(array('web_update'=>date("Y-m-d",strtotime(' -1 day', $time)), 'authcode'=>$authcode));
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'."\n";
echo $result->GetCikkekAuthResult->any;
?>
```

Which outputs me a nice XML that i can import in WP woocommerce. However there is a line in the XML that handles the Stock of the product.

```
<cikk cikkid="15419">
..
<webmegjel>2</webmegjel>
..
</cikk>
```

The problem is. Woocommerce doesn't recognize the number as a valid stock information. 1 - in stock 2 - out of stock.

How should i modify the php code to change all the *2* to outofstock and the 1-s to instock in the final XML output?

I know how to change a value in a physical XML, but this one will never be saved, only the php will be called once a day. So itt has to be made on the fly while the php runs.

Comment: The fact that the XML string came from SOAP, and is going to Woocommerce, is all irrelevant detail. Your actual question is simply "How do I modify an XML string in PHP?" I think there are probably plenty of tutorials for that elsewhere, with many different approaches to the problem, so am voting to close this as "Too Broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This done the trick:

```
$response = $result->GetCikkekAuthResult->any;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$cikkek = $xml->xpath('/valasz/cikk');
foreach ($cikkek as &$cikk){
    switch ($cikk->webmegjel) {
        case '1': $cikk->webmegjel = 'instock'; break;
        case '2': $cikk->webmegjel = 'outofstock'; break;
        case '3': $cikk->webmegjel = 'outofstock'; break;
        default: $cikk->webmegjel = 'outofstock';
    }
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $xml->asXml();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a text replacement on the result XML string:
Replace "<webmegjel>1<" to "<webmegjel>instock<"
Replace "<webmegjel>2<" to "<webmegjel>outofstock<"

For example:

```
<?php
$xmlString = '<cikk cikkid="15419">
<othertsuff>...</othertsuff>
<webmegjel>2</webmegjel>
<othertsuff>...</othertsuff>
<webmegjel>1</webmegjel>
</cikk>
';

$searchArray = array('<webmegjel>1<','<webmegjel>2<');
$replaceArray = array('<webmegjel>instock<','<webmegjel>outofstock<');    
$replacedString = str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $xmlString);

echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($replacedString).'<pre>';
?>
```